# How can I replace sequential citation numbers with an en dash in the ACS bibliography style for Microsoft Word?

Tags: xml, xslt, bibliography, citations

I need to change a little bit of the ACS bibliography style for Microsoft Word to suit my needs. There's a line of code for the citations that has a separator:

```
<citation>
      <openbracket>(</openbracket>
      <closebracket>)</closebracket>
      <separator>, </separator>
```

The result would be that if the user cited more than one reference it would like like this:

The chemicals were sufficient (*1, 2, 3*).

However, I need it to remove the numbers in between if they were in sequence and replace them with an en dash.

The chemicals were sufficient (*1–3*).

So far, I got almost everything I needed from the file except how to check for if there were a sequence of numbers and replace the numbers in between with an en dash. Here are a few examples of what I need:

1. The chemicals were sufficient (*1*). [This works]
2. The chemicals were sufficient (*1, 2*). [This works]
3. The chemicals were sufficient (*1–3*). [I need to implement this]
4. The chemicals were sufficient (*1, 3–6*). [ I need to implement this]

Here is a link to the code: https://github.com/codingo/BibWord/blob/master/source/BibWord/Styles/ACSCitSeq.xsl

The separator is found on line 138.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.